# Show components in Altium schematic, but exclude from design

Tags: schematics, altium

I am designing an I2C multiplexer circuit in Altium 17.0 which includes a reset input through a transistor.

In this particular PCB, the reset function will not be needed, and the reset pin of the mux will just be tied to ground. But, I have a small sub-circuit (input port, transistor, three resistors, output port) that generally would be included with this multiplexer.

[image]

To save myself time in the future, I would like to leave this sub-circuit on the schematic, but somehow disable it. Obviously, I could just create a copy of the schematic for future reference, but then I'd have to maintain two versions.

**How can I "disable" these components so they are not annotated, compiled, or copied to the PCB, but stay on the schematic?**

Comment: A better solution (in my opinion!) is to save these little bits of circuitry as "Snippets". Then they can easily be re-used in other schematics. This also means that you don't have to leave non-functioning components cluttering the schematic and potentially causing confusion to other engineers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a Compile Mask -- this masks the items under it such that they don't get "compiled". I'm pretty sure this also prevents them from getting copied to the PCB.

[image]

Then you get this:

[image]

And it should be left out of annotation, ERCs, etc.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  I've used Altium for years and never noticed that feature.  I tried and it does remove the components from the PCB, BOM, etc.   Very nice tool.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is by creating "variants". You can create multiple variants, each one including or excluding components by changing the component's status to "Not Fitted". Setting up variants can be a long process to begin with, so instead of posting a tutorial here I will leave the link below, which is Altium's technical documentation on the "variants" system. If you have any specific questions, feel free to edit your post or create a new one.

http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/True+Variants

Comment: Ehm... I'm afraid, not quite. Directly from the docs: "If a component is set to Not Fitted, it still exists on the schematic and is transferred to the PCB, but it is removed from the appropriate output documentation, such as the BoM."